# Is elderly friend correct?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

How to say "My friend who is an elderly person" in one word? If we say "old friend" it usually means "A person who has been my friend for a long time". So what should we say instead?

Comment: If it's someone eligible for a state pension (usually over 65), then here in the UK we might call that person a "pensioner".  E.g. "My friend who is a pensioner". It's fairly informal, and doesn't have any negative connotations. This word might not work in other English speaking countries however.

Comment: Nice! I'm not a native English speaker, but "My friend who is a pensioner" sounds interesting to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elderly friend" is two words, but works well enough.

It would be rather rare in actual use.  I would prefer the longer form "A friend who is ...." in most contexts.

> I have a friend who is 84, which proves that teenagers can be friends with elderly people.